# php foreach insert instead of echo

Tags: php

I have a calendar, instead of events, the 'title' is a persons name, and the date and time they are giving their availability for.  The calendar is built, and works, and the 'submit new availability' works.

What I am in great need of, is the ability for the user to be able to have ability to make it a recurring event.

I know how to use for each and they pick a start and end date, and how to make it increment by one day until the end date, but I know how to echo that, how can I insert it instead of simply echo it?

Example:  Employee wants to give availability for 2015-05-01 from 0700 until 1500 and be available until 2015-05-10 (same times 0700 until 1500)

The following code outputs what I would be looking for, I do not know how to insert a new record for each with the outputted date incremented (instead of 'echo')

Any help? Please and thank you?

```
    <?php

$begin = new DateTime( '2012-08-01' );  //this could be my $_POST['start']
$end = new DateTime( '2012-08-31' );   //this could be my $_POST['end']
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Ymd") . "<br>";    // works but want to have rows         inserted and each start date increments by one day, instead of echo to the page
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rows"? Rows in a PHP array? Rows in an HTML table? In a database table?

Comment: It inserts into mysql database (php).  As it is now, they pick a date, pick start time, pick end time, click submit; it inserts as a new row (record).  I am trying to figure out how to make it so they pick and end date for the recurring rule, so if they pick 5 days later, it inserts for rows, with each start date incrementing by one.  I hope that makes sense?  The point is the person could actually be available for 20 days in a row, the same start and end time, I do not want them to have to enter that data 20 times and each time change the start date by one...

Comment: I am sorry ^ about the typo above, I meant to type if they pick an end date five days later, then it inserts five times  (and inputs day1 day 2 day3 day4 day5, with same start and end times)